# POST 500 (Internal Server Error) using Ajax, React and Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, reactjs

I'm just taking a step to use Ajax so I may missed something very important. Instead of having the page to refresh, I now want to use ajax. I'm testing a small code but the browser console says:

> POST 500 (Internal Server Error)

**Routes:**

```
post 'to/test' => 'foo#bar'
```

**.jsx:**

```
test(e){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'to/test',
      type: 'POST',
    });
},
```

**foo_controller.rb:**

```
def bar
 u = User.last
 u.age = 99
 u.save
end
```

Looking at my rails console, the user's age was set to 99. Anything I've missed in my ajax learning?

Comment: how about the Rails log file? 500 error is about internal server error, show us. I am pretty sure I know the answer, it's  `Template is missing`.

Comment: @Зелёный It's looking for a template. I dont need a template. How to prevent this? A redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure I know the answer, it's a `Template is missing` error, just add [`head :ok`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Head/head):

```
def bar
  u = User.last
  u.age = 99
  u.save
  head :ok
end
```

**`head(status, options = {})`**

> Returns a response that has **no content** (merely headers). The options
>   argument is interpreted to be a hash of header names and values. This
>   allows you to easily return a response that consists only of
>   significant headers.

Comment: `head :ok` was best. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

`url: 'to/test'`

To this:

`url: '/to/test'`

Otherwise the ajax call will use the path local to the current path, not the path local to the domain.

Edit: scrap that, a 500 error probably means something else. What do your server logs say? You may need to ensure that the action method responds to js with a `respond_to` block, and have a `bar.js.erb` template file to go with it.